# View showing incorrect data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-view

I have a very simple database.  It contains 3 tables.  The first is the primary input table where values go in.  The 2nd and 3rd are there purely for translating values to names for a view.  When I view the rows in table 1, I can see that column businessUnit contains valid values in all rows.  When I add the Business_Units table (The 3rd table in this DB), all but 2 rows go away and despite the businessUnit value both being `1` in the 1st table, the view gives them different names.

I created a DB diagram and uploaded a screenshot to imgur.  Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/imSkq.jpg

[image]

I only have 2 relationships in the table.  One from equipType on New_Equipment_User to id in Equipment_Type and one from businessUnit in New_Equipment_User to id in Business_Units.  The weird thing is that the Equipment Type works perfectly, yet when I replicate the table, relationship and view information exactly, it doesn't work.  Instead of 6 rows appearing, there are only 2 which share the same value in businessUnit, but gives 2 different names for it.

In case it matters, here is my view Query:

```
SELECT dbo.New_Equipment_User.id, dbo.Equipment_Type.name AS equipType, dbo.New_Equipment_User.jobNumber,     dbo.New_Equipment_User.costCode, 
  dbo.New_Equipment_User.reason, dbo.New_Equipment_User.mobile, dbo.New_Equipment_User.mobileQty, dbo.New_Equipment_User.mobileComment, 
  dbo.New_Equipment_User.laptop, dbo.New_Equipment_User.laptopQty, dbo.New_Equipment_User.laptopComment, dbo.New_Equipment_User.desktop, 
  dbo.New_Equipment_User.desktopQty, dbo.New_Equipment_User.desktopComment, dbo.New_Equipment_User.modem, dbo.New_Equipment_User.modemQty, 
  dbo.New_Equipment_User.modemComment, dbo.New_Equipment_User.printer, dbo.New_Equipment_User.printerQty, dbo.New_Equipment_User.printerComment, 
  dbo.New_Equipment_User.camera, dbo.New_Equipment_User.cameraQty, dbo.New_Equipment_User.cameraComment, dbo.New_Equipment_User.dateRequired, 
  dbo.New_Equipment_User.requestedBy, dbo.New_Equipment_User.dateRequested, dbo.New_Equipment_User.approvalStatus, 
  dbo.Business_Units.name AS businessUnit
FROM dbo.New_Equipment_User
     JOIN dbo.Equipment_Type ON dbo.New_Equipment_User.equipType = dbo.Equipment_Type.id
     JOIN dbo.Business_Units ON dbo.New_Equipment_User.id = dbo.Business_Units.id
WHERE  (dbo.New_Equipment_User.approvalStatus = '0')
```

And here is an image of the view since it is easier to read: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTACs.jpg

[image]

Is anyone able to assist with why this might be happening?

Comment: You'll need to post some data (not images please).

Comment: Why don't you use aliases for table names? Your code would be twice shorter.

Comment: I'm just trying to make it work before it is prettied up.

Comment: Please format your message using aliases !

Answer (score 1):

Try using a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT ...

FROM dbo.New_Equipment_User
     JOIN dbo.Equipment_Type ON dbo.New_Equipment_User.equipType = dbo.Equipment_Type.id
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Business_Units ON dbo.New_Equipment_User.id = dbo.Business_Units.id
```

This will ensure that all `dbo.New_Equipment_User` and all `dbo.Equipment_Type` is present

Comment: Hey.  That has got me closer.  It is still showing NULL when it should be giving me the name, that said it is now displaying all columns like it should be.

Comment: `dbo.Equipment_Type.name` is null?

Comment: No, the Equipment Type has always worked, it is the `dbo.Business_Units.name` field. Despite there being data in each row for that column that matches the key in its table, it either displays incorrect data (The table says 1 which is Corporate, but it shows Civil) or it displays NULL.